# Accuracy with Double

Tags: java

I have the following input:

37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629
91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250
23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676

And I want to store it maintaining at least 10sf accuracy.

My code:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
    DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("#");

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e);
    }



    while(br.readLine() != null) {
        String x = d.format(Double.parseDouble(br.readLine()));
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

At this point, however, I can I convert x to double maintaining accuracy?

Thanks :)

Comment: Well what happens at the moment? Note that you're calling `readLine()` twice per iteration, which isn't what you want...

Comment: It works fine, but the result is a string, not a double...

Comment: Well that's because you're calling `d.format` - don't do that! You're already parsing the value using `Double.parseDouble`, but then you're *just* formatting the result. But the duplicate call to `readLine()` is definitely a bug...

Comment: But if I just parse as double it won't retain precision, will it?

Comment: It will retain about 15 digits. It won't be *exact*, but you said you only need about 10 significant digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to maintain around 15 significant digits of accuracy with a `double`. You just need to keep hold of the value returned by `Double.parseDouble` instead of *just* formatting it. You also need to only read each line once:

```
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    double value = Double.parseDouble(line);
    // Use value...
}
```

If you *actually* need the exact value (rather than the 10 significant digits stated in the question), you should use `BigInteger` if they're all integers, or `BigDecimal` if some values will actually be non-integers.

Comment: +1 or leave it as a String if you want to keep the original value.